# NPO в методе insert при использовании Room

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

при попытке создать запись в БД Sqlite используя Room, получаю NPE.
Немного кода:
Модель

```
@Entity
public class Elements {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long elementId;

    public String name;
    
    public Elements(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

метод в Dao

```
    @Insert
    Maybe<Long> insert(Elements element); //NPE генерируется здесь
```

Хотя стоит флаг авто-генерации id, он не создается. Пробовал явно задавать elementId = 0, как пишут в некоторых ответах в интернете, но ситуация не меняется. Почитав документацию не совсем понял что значит "If the field type is long or int (or its TypeConverter converts it to a long or int), Insert methods treat 0 as not-set while inserting the item."

В какую сторону стоит копать?

Comment: Что такое NPO? Что если тип сделать объектным, т.е. Long, вместо long?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб прошу прощения, имел ввиду NullPointerException.
Пробовал с Long и Integer, картина не меняется. В документации написано: "If the field's type is Integer or Long (or its TypeConverter converts it to an Integer or a Long), Insert methods treat null as not-set while inserting the item." Исходя из этого я не совсем понимаю какой тип выбрать и как будет правильным его использовать

Comment: Очень странно. Может быть в логе ошибки какие-то подробности есть? Можете его показать? Может быть конструктор стоит убрать?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб если убрать конструктор, как тогда передавать экземпляр класса в метод insert?
Exception:

Attempt to invoke interface method 'io.reactivex.Maybe com.dbuzin.warehouseorder.dao.ElementsDao.insert(com.dbuzin.warehouseorder.enteties.Elements)' on a null object reference
        at com.dbuzin.warehouseorder.presenters.ActivityElementsPresenter.addElement(ActivityElementsPresenter.java:23)

метод presentera: 
`public void addElement(Elements element){
        elementsDao.insert(element).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())...`

Comment: Судя по логу у вас Dao null. Именно тут проблема

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо, Ваш ответ навел на мысль. Тут скорее Entity null, но как его правильно создать с Dagger не могу найти. Я думал при создании `@Module RoomDatabase` он подтягивается автоматом.

Comment: Скорее null всё же Dao, а не модель. Проверить это просто - выведите в консоль оба объекта и увидите какой из них null. После этого да, надо будет, видимо, с DI разбираться, а не с Room.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была немного глубже, dagger не инжектил зависимость в presenter.
Было:

```
@InjectViewState
public class ActivityElementsPresenter extends MvpPresenter<ActivityElementsView> {
    @Inject
    ElementsDao elementsDao;

    // здесь должен быть вызов инжекта самого presenter

    public void addElement(Elements element){
        elementsDao.insert(element).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())...
    }
}
```

Решение:

```
@InjectViewState
public class ActivityElementsPresenter extends MvpPresenter<ActivityElementsView> {
    @Inject
    ElementsDao elementsDao;

    public ActivityElementsPresenter(){
       App.getAppComponent().inject(this);//calling the dagger's injector to inject dependency.
    }

    public void addElement(Elements element){
        elementsDao.insert(element).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())...
    }
}
```